# ListView layout height not matching the parent inside RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I have RecyclerView with Horizontal scroll inside a fragment. There are TextView and ListView Inside the RecyclerView.

The ListView height is not matching the parent Height as expected.

**This is how it looks:**

[image]

[image: Layout Bound Screenshot]

**This list Recycler View Layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_DateTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="13/03/2019 - 6.30 PM"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/id_ListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/browser_actions_title_color"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**And My Adapter class file:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    cardview_Listview cardview_listview = cardview_listviews.get(position);
    holder.tv_DateTime.setText(cardview_listview.getS_DateTime());
    holder.setListView(cardview_listview.getS_EntryList());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cardview_listviews.size();
}    
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv_DateTime;
    ListView listView;

    ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_DateTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_DateTime);
        listView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_ListView);
    }

    void setListView(List<String> s_entryList) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, s_entryList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**I have tried some threads but none worked**:

- [ListView inside ScrollView not Showing all items in the in the Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387019/listview-inside-scrollview-not-showing-all-items-in-the-in-the-adapter)
- [Android: RecyclerView not showing List Items in a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827981/android-recyclerview-not-showing-list-items-in-a-fragment)

This my test app which I tried and got what I expected:
[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set your `LinearLayout` height and width to `match_parent`.

Comment: Can you tell me what do you expect as a result ?

Comment: Take a look at your fragment container size

Comment: even though i set width match parent and height wrap content except for the ListView and the other way still same result.

Comment: i have update the thread please take a look at the screenshot

Comment: When I saw your desired results I started thinking about maybe your recyclerView is displaying only the first item.

Comment: yes eve i thought that too but the list view shows small scrollbar which is clearly visible in the first column and i even went ahead and checked the size of the list i shows correctly as 17 which is the queue which is expected.

Comment: hmmm  i am sorry this is the Commercial application so i can not show the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, removing `layout_marginEnd` will work

Comment: i have removed that also but no change

Comment: one way of debugging on your own is to turn on `Show layout bounds`  in your developer settings

Comment: Please answer relevant to question.